# Загрузка сведений о выбранных в ListBox студентах из файла txt в MEMO

Tags: c++builder, c++

Задача такова:

По нажатию кнопки «Сведения» данные о выбранных в правом ListBox студентах отображаются в поле Memo. Данные о студентах хранятся в файле. По нажатию кнопки «Готово» должна выводиться форма с табелем на выбранного студента. Последняя форма должна выводиться на печать.

Прошу, помогите, чем сможете. Единственное, что мне пришло в голову, это как-то связать Имя студента с текстовым файлом, но не представляю, как это сделать.

Скриншот программы:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если самый простой вариант:

```
if (ListBox1->Items->Strings[ListBox1->ItemIndex] == AnsiString("Васин А.В.") {
    Memo1->Lines->LoadFromFile(L"C:\\vasin.txt");
}
```

**Обновление**

Пишите конкретнее, что требуется от работы программы. Если вы хотите динамический список студентов, то можно при старте программы заполнять листбокс из файла.

```
if (ListBox1->Items->Strings[ListBox1->ItemIndex] ==  AnsiString("Васин А.В.")) {
    Memo1->Lines->LoadFromFile(L"C:\\vasin.txt");
}
```

Проверил, работает. `ListBox1->ItemIndex` - это пункт, который в данный момент выделен в `ListBox1`.

Comment: Спасибо, а вот если надо будет пополнить список студентов, и не дополнять код, есть ли универсальный способ который сам определит что нужно показать?

Comment: У меня почему то ваш код не работает, ItemIndex нехочет принимать, попробовал так: 

    while(ListBox2->Items->Count > 0)
    {
    if (ListBox2->Items->Strings[0] == AnsiString("Âàñèí À.Â."))
    {
        Memo3->Lines->LoadFromFile("vasin.txt");
    }
    if (ListBox2->Items->Strings[0] == AnsiString("Èâàíîâ Ñ.È."))
    {
        Memo3->Lines->LoadFromFile("ivanov.txt");
    }
      }

Программа загружает сведения, но только по одному из них, и сразу зависает.

Comment: Пишите конкретнее, что требуется от работы программы. Если вы хотите динамический список студентов, то можно при старте программы заполнять листбокс из файла.

if (ListBox1->Items->Strings[ListBox1->ItemIndex] ==  AnsiString("Васин А.В.")) {
  Memo1->Lines->LoadFromFile(L"C:\\vasin.txt");
 }
Проверил, работает. ListBox1->ItemIndex - это пункт, который в данный момент выделен в ListBox1